# Angular 2 Image not showing

Tags: image, angular

So I have a very basic issue.

Images are not showing in my Angular 2 application.

This is how I define an image:

```
<img alt="logo" [src]="'./images/logo.png'">
```

Is there a package I'm supposed to install to make images work?

BTW I'm new to Angular as you can probably guess!

Answer (score 1):

Property binding ('[]') : To set a property of a view element to the value of a template expression.

```html
<img alt="logo" src="'./images/logo.png'">
```

just works fine

Comment: That works but I've now ran into a new issue, which I've described as a comment on the other answer.

Comment: @TheS, a screen shot of the console helps

Comment: [Screenshot here.](http://image.prntscr.com/image/dcc40a01c22b406f9318e2ee3d282a41.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your image url is a known value as you seem to be indicating here, there's no need for any special angular property binding.

Simply specify your image tag using normal HTML:

```
<img alt="logo" src="images/logo.png">
```

Note that the path above is a relative path

Comment: OK, I now get this issue:
Module parse failed: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\yyy\frontend\app\images\logo.png Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: [Screenshot here.](http://image.prntscr.com/image/dcc40a01c22b406f9318e2ee3d282a41.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install an image loader

Try [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) then you should add in your webpack this rules

```
    module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

it should work now